# Amcharts time series data, first label showing date

Tags: amcharts

I want to display only time series. but by default first label showing date. I want it to show "00:00"

https://i.stack.imgur.com/PdWuZ.png

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PdWuZ.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set [`markPeriodChange`](https://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/CategoryAxis#markPeriodChange) to false in your `categoryAxis` to prevent the axis from bolding and using a different date format for the first date:

```
AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
  // ...
  categoryAxis: {
    // ...
    markPeriodChange: false,
    // ...
  }
});
```